# Relative Strength Index in Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, finance, technical-indicator

I am trying to code an RSI (which has been a good way for me to learn API data fetching and algorithms already).

The API I am fetching data from comes from a reputable exchange so I know the values my algorithm is analyzing are correct, that's a good start.

The issue I'm having is that the result of my calculations are completely off from what I can read on that particular exchange and which also provides an RSI indicator (I assume they analyze their own data, so the same data as I have).

I used the exact same API to translate the Ichimoku indicator into code and this time everything is correct! I believe my RSI calculations might be wrong somehow but I've checked and re-checked many times.

I also have a "literal" version of the code where every step is calculated like an excel sheet. It's pretty stupid in code but it validates the logic of the calculation and the results are the same as the following code.

Here is my code to calculate the RSI :

```
    let period = 14

    // Upward Movements and Downward Movements
    var upwardMovements : [Double] = []
    var downwardMovements : [Double] = []

    for idx in 0..<15 {
        let diff = items[idx + 1].close - items[idx].close
        upwardMovements.append(max(diff, 0))
        downwardMovements.append(max(-diff, 0))
    }

    // Average Upward Movements and Average Downward Movements
    let averageUpwardMovement1 = upwardMovements[0..<period].reduce(0, +) / Double(period)
    let averageDownwardMovement1 = downwardMovements[0..<period].reduce(0, +) / Double(period)

    let averageUpwardMovement2 = (averageUpwardMovement1 * Double(period - 1) + upwardMovements[period]) / Double(period)
    let averageDownwardMovement2 = (averageDownwardMovement1 * Double(period - 1) + downwardMovements[period]) / Double(period)

    // Relative Strength
    let relativeStrength1 = averageUpwardMovement1 / averageDownwardMovement1
    let relativeStrength2 = averageUpwardMovement2 / averageDownwardMovement2

    // Relative Strength Index
    let rSI1 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength1 + 1))
    let rSI2 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength2 + 1))

    // Relative Strength Index Average
    let relativeStrengthAverage = (rSI1 + rSI2) / 2

    BitcoinRelativeStrengthIndex.bitcoinRSI = relativeStrengthAverage
```

Readings at 3:23pm this afternoon give `73.93` for my algorithm and `18.74` on the exchange. As the markets are crashing right now and I have access to different RSIs on different exchanges, they all display an RSI below `20` so my calculations are off.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: That code [looks familiar](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/183880)

Comment: Absolutely Martin! :) That was my old account, so the code is more than a month old and I can confirm something is off ..

Comment: What is the (concrete) input data, what output do you get and what do you expect? At what point in the code are the values not as they should be?

Comment: This is the API I am using `https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:30m:tBTCUSD/hist`.  The data is correct, and everything is fine in the code but the resulting value doesn't match what the Bitfinex's RSI indicator displays. That makes me wonder if my RSI calculations are wrong of they (Bitfinex) use a different method for theirs.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering this 2 years later, but hopefully it helps someone.

RSI gets more precise the more data points you feed into it. For a default RSI period of 14, you should have at least 200 previous data points. The more, the better!

Let's suppose you have an array of close candle prices for a given market. The following function will return RSI values for each candle. You should always ignore the first data points, since they are not precise enough or the number of candles is not the 14 (or whatever your `periods` number is).

```swift
func computeRSI(on prices: [Double], periods: Int = 14, minimumPoints: Int = 200) -> [Double] {
    precondition(periods > 1 && minimumPoints > periods && prices.count >= minimumPoints)

    return Array(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: prices.count) { (buffer, count) in
        buffer.initialize(repeating: 50)
        
        var (previousPrice, gain, loss) = (prices[0], 0.0, 0.0)
        for p in stride(from: 1, through: periods, by: 1) {
            let price = prices[p]

            let value = price - previousPrice
            if value > 0 {
                gain += value
            } else {
                loss -= value
            }

            previousPrice = price
        }

        let (numPeriods, numPeriodsMinusOne) = (Double(periods), Double(periods &- 1))
        var avg = (gain: gain / numPeriods, loss: loss /numPeriods)
        buffer[periods] = (avg.loss > .zero) ? 100 - 100 / (1 + avg.gain/avg.loss) : 100

        for p in stride(from: periods &+ 1, to: prices.count, by: 1) {
            let price = prices[p]
            avg.gain *= numPeriodsMinusOne
            avg.loss *= numPeriodsMinusOne

            let value = price - previousPrice
            if value > 0 {
                avg.gain += value
            } else {
                avg.loss -= value
            }

            avg.gain /= numPeriods
            avg.loss /= numPeriods

            if avgLoss > .zero {
                buffer[p] = 100 - 100 / (1 + avg.gain/avg.loss)
            } else {
                buffer[p] = 100
            }
            
            previousPrice = price
        }

        count = prices.count
    }
}
```

Please note that the code is very imperative to reduce the amount of operations/loops and get the maximum compiler optimizations. You might be able to squeeze more performance using the Accelerate framework, though. We are also handling the edge case where you might get all gains or losses in a periods range.

If you want to have a running RSI calculation. Just store the last RSI value and perform the RSI equation for the new price.

Comment: do you have an example hot to compute Average True Range?

Comment: Hey @Shial, sadly I don't.